Power automate desktop - cannot login
I installed power automate desktop via MSI installer to a mac m1 on Parallels.
It starts up fine, and asks me to press a login button. After pressing the button, i get an infinite spinner that says it is logging in.
Never did it ask for any credentials. Not getting past this screen.
Should I let it work for over an hour and just wait, or is there something that I should do to force it to use certain credentials etc.?

Okay, after a while I tried to do a fresh install of Windows 11 on a new parallels vm.

Let it install all OS updates
Install office 365
Install Power Automate Desktop from official MSI

It worked.
The old vm was same OS with same software, but somehow this worked now. Leaving this here if somebody else has the same problem :)
Also, PAD uses the language that is set to 'preferred' language in Windows system settings even if your OS is in english. To change this, install english language package, set it as default and then reboot.
